# Realm any way to store JSONArray without parsing json data

Tags: android, realm

this below json, is simple data which i get from webservice

```
[
  {
    "section_month_name": "month one",
    "month_title": "title of month",
    "section_price": "150000",
    "section_available": true,
    "section_lessons": [
      {
        "time": "30.12",
        "media": "music",
        "course": "free",
        "title": "title 1",
        "content": "content 1",
        "file_url": "http:www.google.com/file_1.tmp"
      },
      {
        "time": "30.12",
        "media": "music",
        "free_course": true,
        "title": "title 2",
        "content": "content 2",
        "file_url": "http:www.google.com/file_1.tmp"
      }
    ],
    "lessons_count": 4
  }
]
```

`MonthSections` schema:

```
public class MonthSections extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private RealmList<SectionLesson> lessons;
    private String section_month_name;
    private String month_title;
    private String section_price;
    private boolean section_available;
    private int lessons_count;
    public MonthSections() {
    }

    /* setters and getters */
}
```

`SectionLesson` schema:

```
public class SectionLesson extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String file_url;
    private String time;
    private String media;
    private String course;
    public SectionLesson() {
    }

    /* setters and getters */
}
```

and my processing json array and save it into database is:

```
try {
    for (int index = 0; index < event.getData().length(); index++) {
        JSONObject month = event.getData().getJSONObject(index);
        RealmList<SectionLesson> sectionLessonList = new RealmList<>();
        realm.beginTransaction();
        JSONArray section_lesson = month.getJSONArray("section_lessons");
        for (int lessonIndex = 0; lessonIndex < section_lesson.length(); lessonIndex++) {
            JSONObject lesson = section_lesson.getJSONObject(lessonIndex);
            SectionLesson sectionLesson = realm.createObject(SectionLesson.class);
            //sectionLesson.setMonthId(latestId.getId());
            sectionLesson.setTitle(lesson.getString("title"));
            sectionLesson.setContent(lesson.getString("content"));
            sectionLesson.setFile_url(lesson.getString("file_url"));
            sectionLesson.setTime(lesson.getString("time"));
            sectionLesson.setMedia(lesson.getString("media"));
            sectionLesson.setCourse(lesson.getString("course"));
            sectionLessonList.add(sectionLesson);
        }
        MonthSections monthSections = realm.createObject(MonthSections.class, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        monthSections.setSection_month_name(month.getString("section_month_name"));
        monthSections.setMonth_title(month.getString("month_title"));
        monthSections.setSection_price(month.getString("section_price"));
        monthSections.setSection_available(month.getBoolean("section_available"));
        monthSections.setLessons_count(month.getInt("lessons_count"));
        monthSections.setLessons(sectionLessonList);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
}
```

**is any simple way to store this array without parsing json data?**

for this code as:

```
realm.createObjectFromJson(SectionLesson .class, json)
```

i get this error:

```
Could not create Json object from string
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"section_month_name":"month 1","month_title":"title","section_price":"150000","section_available":true,"lessons_count":4,"section_lessons":[{"title":"tlt","content":"content","file_url":"http:www.google.com\/file_1.tmp","time":"30.12","media":"music","course":"free"}]}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

and this code as:

```
 realm.executeTransaction(realm -> realm.createAllFromJson(MonthSections.class, event.getData().toString()));
```

return this error:

```
JSON object doesn't have the primary key field 'id'
```

and that need to have key field as 'id'

Comment: You have a conflict your Realm schema have id and your JSON object doesn't, provably there are no best solution, or you keep all as is, or iterate over JSON array and add field id and then use built in Realm method createAllFromJson(), or remove field id from schema (if it unnecessary in your case)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `createObjectFromJson()`?

For single object

```
realm.createObjectFromJson(SectionLesson.class, json)
```

For JSONArray

```
createAllFromJson(SectionLesson.class, jsonArray)
```

Comment: yes i get this error: `Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"section_month_name":"month 1","month_title":"title","section_price":"150000","section_available":true,"lessons_count":4,"section_lessons":[{"title":"tlt","content":"content","file_url":"http:www.google.com\/file_1.tmp","time":"30.12","media":"music","course":"free"}]}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: so use createAllFromJson()

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code in SectionLesson For loop

> sectionLesson.setId(""+ System.currentTimeMillis());

```
 SectionLesson sectionLesson = realm.createObject(SectionLesson.class);
        //sectionLesson.setMonthId(latestId.getId());
        sectionLesson.setId(""+ System.currentTimeMillis());
        sectionLesson.setTitle(lesson.getString("title"));
        sectionLesson.setContent(lesson.getString("content"));
        sectionLesson.setFile_url(lesson.getString("file_url"));
        sectionLesson.setTime(lesson.getString("time"));
        sectionLesson.setMedia(lesson.getString("media"));
        sectionLesson.setCourse(lesson.getString("course"));
        sectionLessonList.add(sectionLesson);
```